# Can PAC Proxy read other website requests?

Tags: privacy, proxy

I'm using my university's PAC proxy file to reach academic websites and research papers. The pac file provided contains a list of sites, in which if i go over to these sites it asks me for my username and passwords, but not for other websites. My question is, if i say, go to stackexchange.com, will my university see which site i am connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will, because you are using the university's network connection. When you are using someone's network connection, always assume they monitor which sites you connect to.

However, depending on the PAC configuration, it is possibly configured to only use the proxy for a given set of domains, and use a direct connection in any other case. If this is the case, then the *proxy* will not see whether you are connecting to StackExchange or not. But the network monitoring tools will still see regardless.

Given that networks like a university usually use WPA-Enterprise with either username and password or a client certificate, it is very likely they can also associate your traffic to you as person, not just your device.

Comment: Thank you, they use a direct access method for other sites but i guess they will be able to log what sites i visit still.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will since the proxy mantains logs of the accessed websites. If this proxy dont keep logs, the university firewall certain will do